# How do I create a new class in css from a bootstrap feature

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am working on moving bootstrap css out of my code.

I want to build various classes I can call from my .css (actually .scss) file.

CSS and I have always trod different paths, but I am just learning it now.

I want to build something like this in a different css class:-

```
<div class="well span4">
```

CSS

```
.datainput {  
well; span4  #<<<<this is where I get lost.  
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sass, classes are extended like this:

```
.datainput {
    @extend .well;
    @extend .span4;
}
```

Which would generate output that looks like this:

```
.well, .datainput {
    // styles here
}

.span4, .datainput {
    // styles here
}
```

If you're using LESS, which is what TB was written in, it would look like this:

```
.datainput {
    .well;
    .span4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I plan to get my CSS sorted out at last!